# Post deployment script that reads environment variable inside deployed pod

Tags: shell, kubernetes, environment-variables, containers, apache-flink

I have kubernetes job whose responsibility is to post a jar to flink (via flink api) and run the Jar.
In response it is going to get a Job id from flink api, which i need to use in test script to see if my job is running or not. The job is going to run inside the container/pod spawned by job.yaml and test script is not going to run from the same pod/container spawned by job.yaml.

If i save this job id as environment variable inside the container/pod spawned by job.yaml, is there a way to access that environment variable outside the pod. I am not even allowed manually to get into the container (to print environment variables) using kubectl exec -it podname /bin/bash/ command saying I cant get in inside a completed (not running) Pod..So I am not sure if i can do the same via script..

Are there any alternatives for me to access the job id in test scripts by making use of  environment variable i set inside the container/pod (spawned by job.yaml)..?

In summary is there a way to access the environment variable i set inside Pod, by using a script that runs out side of the pod?

Thank you...
Pavan.

Comment: Does your pod stream logs that you can use to get job-id? Or have it write to some storage (NAS/EFS/PVC) that you have access to outside of the pod?

Comment: Can you provide the job.yaml? id like to see whats inside

Answer (score 0):

No you can't use environment variable for that.

You could add an annotation from inside your pod.
For that you will need to setuo:

- Service account to be able to annotate your self
- [Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/)

Then you will be able to access it from another pod/container